# Global exception handling for REST calls in Ember-CLI

Tags: rest, exception, ember.js, ember-cli

In my ember-cli app I use a token based approach to communicate with a secured REST interface on the server side. As tokens expire after some time, I would like to realize the following behaviour:

As soon as the client tries to access the REST service with an expired token, I would like the user to be redirected to the login screen.

Right now I use the 'catch' function on the store's find method while fetching data in the route's model callback. This works quite well. As a matter of fact, there are more REST invocations than the ones that refer to the model store.

What would be the best practice to deal with this situation? In what place should I implement the (exception) handling? As this seems to be a crosscutting concern, I'd like to implement it in a central place.

I prefer to follow an optimistic approach, thus not checking the validity of the token on each and every transition. It will be sufficient if the redirect will take place the moment the application tries to communicate with the REST interface (ie as soon as it gets the error message from the server).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider the global jquery hooks so you can respond to an Auth fail uniformly. See:
  http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/

It's up to you if you want to set window.location or lookup your application controller and use transitionToRoute() for switching to the login route. Make sure that if you use Ember functions to put your code in an Ember.run.once() from your jquery hook function so it occurs on the Ember run loop.

You could also consider using Ember SimpleAuth (which kind of locks you into its paradigm) or even better and a safer long term priposal IMO, doing it from scratch by first following these tutorials:
 - http://coderberry.me/blog/2013/07/08/authentication-with-emberjs-part-1/
 - http://coderberry.me/blog/2013/07/08/authentication-with-emberjs-part-2/

And then this which is newer and incorporates the above tutorials:
 - http://webcloud.info/blog/2014/04/07/emberjs-authentication-the-right-way-javascript-version/